# Problem with iterating array and updating MySQL table

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm using Ajax to send a serialized form to a PHP file, which updates a MySQL database. Some values from the form comes in an array called `VariableAnnualPriceYear`:

- `VariableAnnualPriceYear[1]: 5000`
- `VariableAnnualPriceYear[2]: 10000`
- `VariableAnnualPriceYear[3]: 15000`
- `VariableAnnualPriceYear[4]: 20000`
- `VariableAnnualPriceYear[5]: 25000`

When I iterate the array above to update the database with the values, I expect this result in the table:

`Id | AnnualPriceYear | AnnualPriceAmount | LandContractId
 1         1                  5000                182
 2         2                 10000                182
 3         3                 15000                182
 4         4                 20000                182
 5         5                 25000                182`

But I get this result:

`Id | AnnualPriceYear | AnnualPriceAmount | LandContractId
 1         5                 25000                182
 2         5                 25000                182
 3         5                 25000                182
 4         5                 25000                182
 5         5                 25000                182`

For every iteration, the table gets updated with the last item in the array. Why?

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LandContract SET Name=?, LocationId=?, Link=?, Notes=?, LandOwnerId=?, StartDate=?, EndDate=?, IsTerminated=?, PaymentInterval=?, PriceType=? WHERE Id=?");

$stmt->execute([$Name, $LocationId, $Link, $Notes, $LandOwnerId, $StartDate, $EndDate, $IsTerminated, $PaymentInterval, $PriceType, $Id]);

$Years = $_POST ['VariableAnnualPriceYear'] ;

if( is_array( $Years ) ) {
    foreach ( $Years as $Year => $Price ) {

        $PriceWithDecimals = number_format((float)$Price, 2, '.', '');

        // Insert the variable annual prices into LandContractAnnualPrice
        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE LandContractAnnualPrice SET AnnualPriceYear=?, AnnualPriceAmount=? WHERE LandContractId=?");
        $stmt2->execute([$Year, $PriceWithDecimals, $Id]);

        var_dump($Year, $PriceWithDecimals, $Id);

    };
}
```

**--UPDATE--**
I updated the code with a var_dump and it gives me the following:

- int(1)
- string(7) "5000.00"
- string(3) "182"
- int(2)
- string(8) "10000.00"
- string(3) "182"
- int(3)
- string(8) "15000.00"
- string(3) "182"
- int(4)
- string(8) "20000.00"
- string(3) "182"
- int(5)
- string(8) "25000.00"
- string(3) "182"

This is a var_dump of the array `$Years`;

```php
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "5000"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "10000"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "15000"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "20000"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "25000"
}
```

Comment: Need a better example of the array you are iterating over. Or you can probably add some var_dumps or step thru the code and it will jump right out at you.

Comment: I have updated the code with a var_dump. Everything seems fine with the array. Hmm...?

Comment: So it's one flat array? Not "multidimensional"? This is still not clear. Debug the code. Add an echo statement that shows the values being used in the bind within the loop. Figure out what assumption you've made, then fix it.

Comment: Yes, `VariableAnnualPriceYear` is a flat array.

Comment: Then `foreach ( $Years as $Year => $Price ) {` makes no sense right? You are not getting the values you expect? That what you are seeing?

Comment: I mean where does `$year` even come from? This makes no sense. I assume 1,2... are not the actual years? Try creating a [*a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated the question with a var_dump of the array $Year. I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "where does `$year` even come from?". `$Year` is referring to the item in the current iteration of the foreach loop.

Comment: By the way, the values from var_dump are correct. The problem is that these are not the values that the table gets updated with. It only gets updated with the last item (5 times). See the beginning of my original question.

Comment: Using `foreach ( $Years as $Year => $Price ) {` on that array your first pass through would result with `$Year = 1` and `$Price = "5000"`. That what you want? Seems like the offset, not the year.

Comment: Maybe we can take this to a chat or something. Hard to "fix" when the code doesn't make sense. It's not one little mistake or a typo.

Comment: I mean even the update is goofy. How many rows you want to update? If one, then maybe use a primary key? That update would update every row WHERE `LandContractId=?`.

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you're asking now. This array is the result of a series of number inputs in a form. The name's of these inputs are `VariableAnnualPriceYear[1]`, `VariableAnnualPriceYear[2]`, `VariableAnnualPriceYear[3]` and so on. The index (1, 2 , 3...) represents the year for which the price ("5000", "10000", "15000"...) applies. So, yes, `$Year = 1` and `$Price = "5000"` is correct in the first iteration. Next iteration should be  `$Year = 2` and `$Price = "10000"`. That seem to be the case too, the problem is that the table is updated with `$Year = 5` and `$Price = "25000"` 5 times.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to start a chat. Can you do it?

Comment: OK, thanks form confirming that was what you did intend. Maybe see my comment about the criteria for the UPDATE.

Comment: Nope. Think moderator only. If we keep adding comments it should prompt us eventually :)

Comment: What you are describing is updating 5 rows with each update call - you observe the results after the last insert, which updates ALL the rows with that `LandContractId `. Sorry it took me so long to spot. Is the idea one row per AnnualPriceYear per LandContractId? In that case `WHERE LandContractId=? AND AnnualPriceYear=?`

Comment: DUH! Now I get it. Thanks! Let me see how to fix this.

Comment: In this case, where both the amount of years **and** their values might have been changed, I think the best idea is to first delete all rows where `LandContractId = $Id` and then create new ones.